# Animated Masks in C4

Tags: ios5, c4

I know that it is possible to create layer masks in C4 like this:

```
object.layer.mask = anotherObject.layer;
```

Is there a known way to use an animated mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can animate a mask in a couple of different ways.

First, if you use basic shapes as the object whose layer will become the mask, you can animate them as a you would normally and this becomes an animated mask.

This can be done for any visible object in C4 (i.e. shapes, movies, images, etc...).

For instance:

```
object.layer.mask = aShape.layer;

aShape.animationDuration = 1.0f;
aShape.origin = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

The above can be done with images as well. When using images any clear parts of the image will turn out transparent in your `original` object.

Furthermore, there is an undocumented animatable image method, which is experimental and available only in the latest template.

Using it would look like:

```
NSArray *imageNamesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"imageName01.png",...,nil];

C4Image *animatedImage = [C4Image animatedImageWithNames:imageNamesArray];

object.layer.mask = animatedImage.mask;
```

Essentially, this method creates an *animated gif* style image... But, because this method is brand new / experimental, there isn't any control over the speed of the transitions between images.